# Point domain to wordpress folder in ec2 amazon centos

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, centos, httpd.conf

I have my site hosted at http://52.68.178.242/

I have registered domain gabifrc.org from aws
I'm using httpd24 on crentos

I have set following configurations in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf file.
It seems to change the DocumentRoot but doamin is not in use. How can i point it to the doamin.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
     DocumentRoot /var/www/html/gabifrc
     ServerName www.gabifrc.org
     ServerAlias gabifrc.org
     ErrorLog /var/www/html/gabifrc/error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: That domain does not resolve for me. Is it pointed to the server? You point domains to servers, not the other way around. The virtual host tells the server how to process requests for that domain; but the domain must be pointed to the server first.

Comment: that was my mistake on the ip, i have edited in the question, it points to the server now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with aws route s5, where i allocated nameserver with the ip and worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

In /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf uncomment NameVirtualHost *:80

Restart httpd

In DNS create A record with EIP of the Instance.

This should solve your problem.